# How can I install VNC Server on Red Hat 7.2 that is not connected to the internet?

Tags: redhat, yum, vnc

I have a 64-bit Red Hat 7.2 server that is isolated from the Internet.

I am able to SSH to it easily, as well as transfer files using USB.
I downloaded `VNC-Server-5.0.5-Linux-x64.rpm` and tried to install it

```
yum install VNC-Server-5.0.5-Linux-x64.rpm
```

also tried:

```
rpm -ivh VNC-Server-5.0.5-Linux-x64.rpm
```

but it reported a missing dependency: `xterm`

When I downloaded and transfered `xterm-179-5.EL.x86_64.rpm` it also required another dependency `libXaw.7` and `libtermcap.so.2()`.

When I found `libXaw` and tried to install it, *it* required `x11-data-bitmaps`. I am not sure when will this chain end.

I am not very skilled with linux, and have searched for a single `rpm` file that contains all the required dependencies for VNC Server, but could not find such thing.

Is there a single file `rpm` package that contains all required dependencies for VNC Server for Red Hat 7.2?

Edit: I ran `yum deplist VNC-Server-5.0.5-Linux-x64.rpm` and got a list of 22 unsatisfied dependencies. Is there a single repository I can download that contain all the missing ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the dependency list, download all dependencies and install them.
To check dependency list do `yum deplist {package name}`

Comment: Is there a repository that contains all the dependencies?

Comment: I typed that and got a list of 22 unsatisfied dependencies.

Comment: If you mean single repo to have all you need? I don't know honestly sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Ahmad...
              Remove unnecessary repository (*i3) from the repolist.
yum remove `package-cleanup --leaves` to remove unwanted pakages
then install VNC on your machine rpm -ivh VNC-Server-5.0.5-Linux-x64.rpm

Comment: Can you please re-format your answer? I think you have mixed command line formatting with normal text

Comment: 1. cd /etc/yum.repos.d/  remove unwanted repolist in your repolist directory

Comment: 2.  run package-cleanup --leaves to remove the broken and unwanted packages.

Comment: 3. yum update to update the pakages

Comment: 4. Finally rpm -ivh VNC-Server-5.0.5-Linux-x64.rpm to install the VNC in your machine